# Using default values in model in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to add some category for my Rails post app.

I want them as fixed value so user can choose from the drop down menu the specific category. My migration file looks like this:

```
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :categories do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

What do I have to do to add some fixed value in my categories model?

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You could set constant like `NAMES = %w(category1 category2)` inside `Category` model, add inclusion validation and get values for your dropdown like this: `Category::NAMES`. In this case don't forget to add database index. Obviously you will query posts related to some category.

There is another option though provided by [ActiveRecord::Enum](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html). It lets you declare category field right inside `Post` without `Category` model at all. If you don't need to manage categories outside the codebase (some admin panel), I would recommend this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum category: [:category1, :category2]
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I didn't know about the 'ActiveRecord::Enum' and I was looking for something like this :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add some predefined categories, then this is called "seed data": 
 [Migrations and Seed data](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data).

> To add initial data after a database is created, Rails has a built-in 'seeds' feature that makes the process quick and easy. This is especially useful when reloading the database frequently in development and test environments. It's easy to get started with this feature: just fill up `db/seeds.rb` with some Ruby code, and run `rails db:seed`:

```
Category.create(name: 'category 1')
Category.create(name: 'category 2')
```